# decode json encoded string back to literal html values in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have a very basic example site here:

http://simondouglas.com/stackexchange/jsonencodeproblem/
EDIT: This now works. I'll keep this here for other users.

If you type in "members" you will receive data back as a JSON object, it's in the console. The problem is that I can't seem to decode the author string as literal HTML.

Falling short of manually having to do my own string replacement ( replace `&gt;` for > etc ) is there a way of carrying out the encoding automatically.

*Original* problem:
http://simondouglas.com/stackexchange/jsonencodeproblem/bad.php

( pasting in the source would not work )

*Solution starting on line 60*:

```
        <dt>
        <strong>${name}</strong><br/>
        {{html getAuthorLink()}}
        </dt>
```

There is an attribute you can pass inside the template to use html instead of plain text.

Comment: So, what exactly is wrong with the `author` fields in these objects? I can see only valid HTML as their values.

Comment: You should post the original code here, so if others view this question, they will know what's going on.  Because with the test site updated, the question doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you must decode the values yourself. `escape()`/`unescape()` and their modern world equivalents are for URI encoding and not HTML encoding.

The most common method is to replace the encoded values in your string, however if performance is not really a concern or you would rather rely on a browser implementation you can attempt to use the various DOM construction and extraction techniques.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. http://phpjs.org/functions/html_entity_decode:424

Basically a port of php's html_entity_decode for javascript. Should do what you are asking.

You would also need this as it is a dependency of ^

http://phpjs.org/functions/get_html_translation_table:416

Comment: Hmmm this looks like it would work, but doesn't. Current test site has been updated with your changes. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the issue here is jQuery-tmpl.  It's treating the data as text, not as HTML.  The data is not encoded to start with, jQuery-tmlp is encoding it before printing it.

Instead of returning HTML, add the HTML to the template, and have the JSON return the link and the name, and fill it in accordingly.

```
<dt>
    <strong>${name}</strong><br/>
    <a href="${authorLink}">${authorName}</a>
</dt>
```

Or build the HTML using jQuery and append it with `append`.

Comment: You are totally right, and this lead me to another search which brought me to this: http://api.jquery.com/template-tag-html/

There is a parameter you can pass into the template. I've updated the test site.